# Is it possible to encode Arabic characters to ISO-8859-6 or Windows-1256 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm actually looking for a javascript function (or library) that can work like Java's java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String s, String encoding) but if that's not possible how can you encode Arabic characters into single-byte coded arabic character set like ISO-8859-6 or Windows-1256.

Comment: I hope somebody gives us an answer soon!

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have anything like that built-in., because that is usually only needed for reading or writing files, that JS can't do anyway, and any HTTP communication is automatically converted. What are you trying to do? Why do you need to convert between charset encoding?

Comment: The requirement is to use single-byte coded arabic characters in the HTTP Servlet Request (Get) from javascript.  Is there anything out there to make this requirement work?  UTF-8 (multi byte) is currently not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately JavaScript only supports UTF-8 encoding when using `encodeURIComponent` (which strictly speaking is the correct thing to do because URL encoding with a different charset is technically possible, but not standardized).

If you want the browser to do the encoding, then (AFAIK) it's not possible with AJAX.

Browsers do it in forms with `accept-charset`:

```
<form action="/some-url" method="get" accept-charset="ISO-8859-6">
  <input name="test">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So you could generate such a form with JavaScript, submit it to an `iframe` and then read it's content.

If that isn't an option, I guess you'll need to write your own URI encoder. Something like this:

```
var iso_8859_6_encoding = {"ء": "C1", "آ": "C2", "أ": "C3", "ؤ": "C4" /* etc. */};

function encodeURIComponentWithCharset(str, charset) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    var char = str.charAt(i);
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) < 128) {
       result += encodeURIComponent(char);
    } elseif (charset[char]) {
       result += "%" + charset[char];
    } else {
       // Drop undefined chars
    }
  } 
  return result;
}

encodeURIComponentWithCharset("your string", iso_8859_6_encoding);
```

(Untested. Encoding from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-6 )

Comment: This is a well-explained, well-constructed answer. It would have been nice if there was a "standard" way to do URL encoding with a different character set but I think there wouldn't be a problem write our own encoder. Thanks.